# Article and Comment classes: Who's responsible for what?

Tags: oop, separation-of-concerns

Considering the [Law of Demeter](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/), [Single Responsibility Principle](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SrpInRuby) and [Tell, Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle; What is the correct relationship between the *Article* and *Comment* class?

**A:** The *Comment* is a concern of *Article* class. It can *Read*, *Create*, *Update* and *Delete* comments. The *Comment* class itself is just a read-only representation of the *Comment* concept.

**B:** The *Comment* is a concern of *HandleComments* class. It can *Create* new comments and assign them to the respective articles. It can also *Read*, *Update* and *Delete* comments. The *Comment* class itself is just a read-only representation of the *Comment* concept.

**C:** The *Comment* is not a concern of neither *Article* or *HandleComments* classes. It has all the CRUD functionality by itself. It can *Assign* itself to an article as well.

**D:** The *Comment* could be a concern of either *Article* or *HandleComments* classes; However they can only *Read*, *Create* and *Delete* comments. The *Update* functionality is a concern of *Comment* class itself.

**Update #1**

Here is how I think about it, however can't really find answers because all of my reading ends up to a non-practical or very simple proof-of-concept examples:

- Do I have to have *readComment*, *createCommnet*, *updateComment* and *deleteComment* classes? According to *Bertrand Meyer* classes with *Verbal* or *PerformSomething* names are signs of danger as they could be methods not classes. So it is okay to have only *Article* and *Comment* classes with all of their respective functionality inside themselves?
- The *Article* and *Comment* doesn't have a `is-a` relationship, so obviously no inheritance here, but they have a `has-a` relationship. I'd go for *Composition* then, but who's responsible for what? If I am a *Comment* then this is my concern to *Update* myself, right? But is that the *Article's* concern to *Delete* me? Hence I'm attached to it.
- Is it the concern of *Article* to load its *Comments*? Or there should be a man-in-the-middle class to handle the relationship between the *Article* and *Comment*? If the *Comment* has loaded by the *Article* then is it a concern of *Article* to be 100% responsible for all of the *Comment* actions?

**Update #2**

More thinking about it, what I really want is *Loosely-Coupled* classes as much as possible. In any case the *Article* class should have a list of *Comments* to iterate between them. In order to assign a *Comment* to an *Article*, I should either pass the *Article* reference to the *Comment* constructor -- the bottom-top way, or I should pass the *Comment* reference to the *AddComment* method of *Article* class -- the top-bottom way.

I prefer the *Bottom-Top-Way*, even tho it looks awkward in the first sight, because then I can have all the other *Comment* actions also within the *Comment* class itself, so the *Article* class will be totally unaware of *Comments* class. The only thing the *Article* class should have is an internal array to hold the *Comments* instances. No need to have *AddComment*, *RemoveComment* methods to the *Article* class.

Is it something that makes sense?

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: @TooTone I'm totally lost basically ... I will try to update tho.

Comment: @TooTone I've updated with more questions! I told you I'm lost ...

Comment: IMO it's v difficult to give a firm answer without knowing a lot more about the system. With use cases one design would likely come out in front. Without that it's possible to think of comments referencing articles, or articles referencing comments. Nevetheless, it's your second bullet point, composition, which strikes me as most natural. To wit, articles have a list of comments, as well as a title, a body, etc. You might or might not have a CommentsList intermediate class. In any case, you can create, delete, and get references to comment objects. Comments have text, links, formatting, etc.

Comment: @TooTone Thanks for the input. I was busy writing the second update while you were posing the comment. I'd really like to know if that makes sense to you as well.

Comment: Articles and comments are just data.

Comment: @Bart Thanks but the whole idea of OOP is to have the `data` and `behavior` in one place and tightly-coupled, right? Are you telling me I should go for the plain-old-data-structures?

Comment: Not really. You need to think more in real world objects. Take a glass for example. Can a glass fill itself with water? No, it can't. You will need someone or some mechanism to poor it in. Can a article write itself? No, it needs a writer and the writer needs some sort of input device. - That is thinking object oriented.

Comment: @Bart Makes sense! What do you suggest then? Should I go for the `CommentHandler` class?

Comment: @Mahdi as your update 2 is more specific I've expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149440/bart) comments, I decided to go for the [Repository Design Pattern](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804), which seems to be one of the battle-tested patterns for handling this kind of cases.

The general idea is to have a *Repository* which is responsible for taking care of *Comments*. So in a broader view a *Blog* should have at least a *postRepository* and *commentRepository* to take care of blog *Posts* and *Comments* functionality.

It is also recommended to handle all of the *List* like data with repository pattern, when there is a need for a kind of central-functionality. In the *Blog* example, it make sense to have repositories for *Categories*, *Tags*, *Users*, etc. as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a lot more about the system it's difficult to answer your question (bar the specifics in update 2). It's possible, for example, to think of comments referencing articles, or articles referencing comments. With more details, especially use cases, it's likely that one design would likely come out in front.

Nevetheless, in the absence of further information, it's your second bullet point, composition, which strikes me as most natural. To wit, articles have a list of comments, as well as a title, a body, etc. You might or might not have a CommentsList intermediate class. In any case, you can create, delete, and get references to comment objects. Comments have text, links, formatting, etc.

Re update 2, I agree that loose coupling is desirable. However I disagree that passing a reference to an Article to the Comment constructor makes sense, all other things being equal. This introduces a cyclic dependency -- because the Article has a list of Comments -- and also therefore a higher degree of coupling than would be the case if you took the alternative "top-bottom" approach of passing the Comment to the AddComment method of the Article class.

With this "top-bottom" approach, the Article could either have a NewComment method, in which case the Article itself creates the Comment object, or it could have an AddComment method as you suggest. Which is preferable depends on the details of the requirements: for example a requirement to have different kinds of comments (or even to share comments between articles) would suggest the AddComment approach.

Comment: Great! Any idea about who should `update` the _Comment_? _Article_ or the _Comment_ itself?

Comment: If the article itself creates comments you have created a dependency. Article and Comment would be tightly coupled. It feels more natural to add to a list of comments.

Comment: @madhi. Depends on what `update` means. If it means updating a database table go for a repository pattern. If it's just settings the contents you'll only need a setter method.

Comment: @Bart yes, modern software design would tend to suggest a [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)-style approach. OTOH, if you pass a comment in by reference, there's nothing to stop the same comment from being added to more than one article, which seems undesirable. Without further information it's hard to be very specific about what would work best.

Comment: @Mahdi re updating the comment, I would go with Bart's comments under your question. The Article and Comment are essentially data. Some other entity in the system gets hold of a comment reference from the article (via a list of comments if necessary), then that entity itself (or another entity to which the comment reference is passed) updates the comment, e.g. according to user import or something else.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for the _Repository Pattern_. I will try to see how far I can get with it. I'd love to up-vote at least if you post your suggestion as an answer as well.

Comment: @TooTone Thanks for all of your suggestions, they're helpful indeed.

Comment: @Bart Just wanted to say that reading more about the repository pattern, it's of course one of the best ways of solving this kind of problems. Thanks a lot for that. Hope you post it as an answer because it might help someone else as well.